# How to programatically add an option to an optiongroup in selectize.js

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I want to dynamically add an option to an optiongroup in Selectize.js.  The API only has

```
addOption(data)
updateOption(value, data)
addOptionGroup(id, data)
```

without much help on what "data" is.  I've seen the examples for adding an option but no mention of using optionGroups

```
$('#button-addoption').on('click', function() {
    control.addOption({
    id: 4,
    title: 'Something New',
    url: 'http://google.com'
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Data is the object passed to the optgroup rendering method.
And so, you can put anything in it.

```
$('#selectize').selectize({
    ...
    optgroupField: 'mygroup',
    render: {
        optgroup_header: function(data, escape) {
            return '<div class="optgroup-header">' + escape(data.a) + escape(data.b) '</div>';
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

And then, whenever you want, you can add groups and options in the selectize:

```
//add group
var optGroup = { a: 'fruit', b: ... };
$('#selectize')[0].selectize.addOptionGroup('0', optGroup);

//add option
var option = { value: 'abc', text: 'banana', mygroup: '1'};            
$('#selectize')[0].selectize.addOption(option);
```

Of course, if you only want a label for the group, you can do this:

```
//code
...
render: {
    optgroup_header: function(data, escape) {
    return '<div class="optgroup-header">' + escape(data) + '</div>';
}
...
//code

$('#selectize')[0].selectize.addOptionGroup('1', 'meat');
```

You can see the [API demo](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/examples/optgroups.html) (search for 'Optgroups (programmatic)' in page).